# Stationary Points - point of inflextion and min and max

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the question "Find the coordinates of any stationary points on each curve and determine whether each stationary point is a maximum, minimum or point of inflection.

Y = X^3 + 3X^2 + 3X"

The solution for this question is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQO8d.jpg)

I understand everything such as differentiating and finding the coordinates. However I do not understand why the coordinates (-1, -1) is point of inflexion.

What is point of inflextion and how can you use the table above to find this or if the stationary point is max or min ?

Comment: Setting the first derivative to zero gives you x-values of any stationary points.

Plugging these points into the second derivative tells you if they are a maximum, minimum, or point of inflection, based on the sign of the second derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a minimum, if the first derivate is $0$ and the second derivate is positive.

We have a maximum, if the first derivate is $0$ and the second derivate is negative.

We have an inflection point , if the second derivate is $0$ and the third derivate is non-zero.

Comment: If we cannot apply one of these rules, we must verify whether the sign of the first (or second) derivate changes. If the second derivate changes its sign, we have an inflection point. If the first derivate changes its sign, we have a minimum, if the sign changes from $-$ to $+$ and a maximum, if the sign changes from $+$ to $-$. Always begin on the "left" side

Comment: What do you mean by derivate could you please elaborate ? Maybe with an example ? I understand everything else just not this rule (:

Comment: You surely had higher derivates , hadn't you ? For example $f(x)=x^2$ has first derivate $2x$ and second derivate $2$. Hence, we have a minimum at $x_0=0$

Comment: Note that we calculate the derivate only at special positions (roots of the first/second derivate). It is NOT meant that the derivate is positive/negative for all real $x$, only for the position we are currently looking at